# When someone says, "I have no words," what does it mean?

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

I contacted a former friend to tell her about a rough situation in my life, and she said to me, "I have no words." What did she mean?

Answer (score 2):

It can have different meanings. In this context seems it is closer to `I am shocked and cannot find any words to console you` or `Any words would only aggravate the situation, so I better not say anything`. But generally, it can also express excitement, amusement, surprise, and many other feelings. Here are a couple of quotes I found:

> "We have no words for speaking of wisdom to the stupid. He who understands the wise is wise already." - G.C. Lichtenberg
>
> "I have no words for my reality." - Max Frisch

Answer (score 2):

"I have no words."   You can hear this in many different situations (in anger, sorrow, joy, regret, etc) as mentioned in another answer, but it will always mean **"I don't know what to say."**
 Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Use of the phrase "have no words" to indicate (as Centaurus says) "not know what to say" goes back much farther than I originally thought it did. The earliest relevant Google Books match for the phrase has the more particular sense "words are inadequate" or "words fail us." From Frederick Faber, [*The Creator and the Creature, Or, the Wonders of Divine Love*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NJ0sW3aEWN0C&pg=PA434&dq=%22have+no+words%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=3sboVJOaEI6togTRk4GIDw&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22have%20no%20words%22&f=false) (1857):

> We **have no words** to tell the power of God. We have no ideas by the help of which we can so much as approach to an honourable conception of it.
>
> ...
>
> If earth be such a heaven to believing souls, what sort of heaven must the real heaven be? What is that incomparable Beauty which the blessed are gazing on this very hour? We **have no words** to tell, no thoughts to think it. What is it that that beauty is doing to their capacious, serene, and glory-strengthened souls? We **have no words** to tell, no thoughts to think it. What is that divine torrent of love which bursts forth from it, and threatens to submerge and overwhelm their separate created lives? We **have no words** to tell, no thoughts to think it.

The notion that the failing is not in the incapacity of words themselves, but in one's inability to summon or speak the appropriate ones, first appears in the Google Books search results in Frederick Harper, [*Wayside Words*](https://books.google.com/books?id=QTUEAAAAQAAJ&pg=RA1-PA155&dq=%22have+no+words%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=NMnoVKbaDYKvogT1i4LwDg&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22have%20no%20words%22&f=false) (1879):

> I offered to join in prayer : "Alas," she said, "I cannot pray, I never have prayed, I **have no words**, and alas, alas, I have no heart." I answered, " The Lord Jesus Christ who died for sinners, and is now at the right hand of God, ever liveth to make intercession for His poor ignorant people."

A somewhat older phrase with essentially the same sense is "at a loss for words." The first instance of that phrase in a Google Books search is from a [letter of November 13, 1722, from Port-Royal, Jamaica](https://books.google.com/books?id=jKQ1AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA109&dq=%22at+a+Loss+for+Words+to+give+a+just+Description%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OMboVLbCH8TZoATJ3oHgDg&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22at%20a%20Loss%20for%20Words%20to%20give%20a%20just%20Description%22&f=false), describing a hurricane there, reprinted in *The Historical Register: Containing an Impartial Relation of All Transactions, Foreign and Domestick. For the Year 1723* (1723):

> And here I confess myself **at a Loss for Words** to give a just Description of the Horror of that Scene that we the Inhabitants saw before our Eyes, when the Terrour of the Sea that broke in upon us from all Quarters, with an impetuous Force, conspir'd with the Violence of the Wind to cut off all Hopes of Safety from us; and we had no other Choice before us, but that dismal one of perishing in the Waters if we fled out of our Houses, or of being bury'd under their Ruins if we continu'd in them.

Although "at a loss for words" comes up only in the context of "don't know what to say," whereas "have no words" can arise in various other circumstances as well as in that one, an Ngram chart tracking the two phrases over the period 1700 to 2000 indicates that "at a loss for words" (red line) has become considerably more common than "have no words" (blue line) in published writing since about 1950:

[image]